# Monitoring Power on Dell Cluster using SNMP

Tags: dell, snmp, electrical-power

I have to monitor/collect Power Values of a dell cluster remotely using SNMP . I have very little experience regarding this. Could anybody guide me through , step by step on how to collect or maybe get a logfile of power values from the dell cluster at an interval of say 1 second ?

EDIT : OK, I learnt that , to get power values , we have to submit the appropriate set of OIDs with SNMP, to be able to access power values.

But any pointers on  what the OID for accessing Power values in a cluster are ? I believe it is manufacture dependent ?

Comment: A dell cluster of what, M1000 blades? servers? equallogic arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the Dell Open Manage Server Administrator ([Dell Linux OMSA Repo](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA)) it includes an SNMP agentX module that the net-snmp daemon and allow you to query all of the Dell specific vendor information. You can get all the MIBs from Dell which will enable you to translate the numeric OIDs to human-readable text that can assist you in easily identifying the ones you're looking for as well as what the values returned mean.

This information can then be monitored by any SNMP-enabled system like Cacti, Nagios, etc to provide trending, tracking and alert notifications.

Comment: I can do an snmpwalk on the dell cluster which returns some
 
`snmpwalk -Oa -c public -v 1 192.168.2.66 system 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.300.10.1.39
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: This system component provides a complete set of remote management functions for modular servers
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.2
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (136194903) 15 days, 18:19:09.03
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: root@localhost
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: Dell Rack System - FNJTJN1`

Do I still have to install Dell Linux OSMA ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a monitoring system like [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/), [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) (there are many others) to make the hard work to you. On most of them all you would need is to learn how to use the data they gather to provide you with graphs.

The other solution is using `snmpwalk`, `snmpget` and other [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpwalk.html) tools to make a shell script and run it with `cron` from time to time to get data and log.

The advantage of tools like the ones I first mentioned is that they already do the hard work for you, but they can be a little too much for small setups, in those cases the script may be better.

Remember that you will need a Read-Only community (SNMP v2) to get data from each of the members of the cluster, and that you will have to decode exactly what value snmp is getting that you need (the snmp values sometimes have strange names, worse yet when it's an unknown [MIB](http://www.paessler.com/support/kb/questions/49)).

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on how I can actually use snmpwalk, Sorry for being so naive, but this is my first time I'm using SNMP and have zero knowledge . How to find power values from snmpwalk . I'd appreciate if you could guide me through this ?